# Upload an image and display it on a webpage with Django

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I'm new at Django and I've been following the django tutorial "djangogirl" but i wanted to add pictures so I did a `model.py` like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
   image = models.ImageField()
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

This is my `view.py`:

```
def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'my_blog/posts.html', {'posts': posts})
```

And `my_blog.html`:

```
{% extends 'my_blog/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style/css/posts.css' %}">

<div id="postsContainer">
    <div id="posts">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div>
            <h3 class="date">Published the: {{ post.published_date }}</h3>
            <h1><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}"/>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
        <div id="button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</button>
        </div>
        <div class="top-divider"></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And I insert my image via the Django admin page.

[image: Image insertion]

The problem is the URL that is returned in my HTML is really weird like: `./images_SseHlrA.png` and it doesn't obviously display the picture correctly. How can I fixed it?

Apparently the picture are 'stocked' at the root level (same level than the file `manage.py` the question is why? and how can I change it and what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alix is right that "You need to specify where to store images uploaded by user" by specifying `upload_to` in the field constructor. But you don't need a special class to handle all of this. Way too complicated. Let's say you have this in your settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

In your template, you should now be able to do something like:

```
<img src="{{ post.image.url }}">
```

Comment: Ok thanks now I got a normal url  "/uploads/illustrations/images.png". But still the picture can't be found. The "uploads" folder is created at the root level and the image is stocked in it in a directory should I import something in my template? like I did for the static file like: {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: If you view source on the rendered page, what URL is given for the image? Now check the Django documentation for MEDIA_URL https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-url - is yours set up and working? MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT are used for definining the location of uploaded media.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify where to store images uploaded by user. Try this in your `models.py`:

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class PathAndRename(object):

    def __init__(self, sub_path):
        self.path = sub_path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        # set filename as random string. change here as you want
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        # return file path
        return os.path.join(self.path, filename)

path_and_rename = PathAndRename("/images")
```

And then in model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename)
```

You can read more about `ImageField` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)